# How can you compare two excel workbooks in python?

Tags: python, excel, comparison, missing-data

I have an excel workbook - sheet1 with values:

```
Names
--------
Aaron  |
Bob    |
Carl   |
Daron  |
Elle   |
```

I have another excel workbook - sheet2 with values:

```
Names       Marks
-------------------
Aaron    |   90
Bob      |   89
```

I want the missing names to be appended in workbook 2 in sheet2 with  "No marks" in 'Marks' column using python.

Can anyone help on this?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Is it 2 workbooks or 1 workbook with 2 sheets ? What ranges are the names in, column A ? Do you have any code to post ?

Comment: Yes it is 2 workbooks

Comment: What is the answer to other 2 questions I asked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

df_list_1 = pd.read_excel (r'data\excel\excel_1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') # Excel with names
df_list_2 = pd.read_excel (r'data\excel\excel_2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') # Excel with names and marks

df_list_1 = df_list_1.reset_index()
df_list_2 = df_list_2.reset_index()

df_diff = df_list_1[~df_list_1['Names'].isin(df_list_2['Names'])] # All names not in the second excel with the marks
df_diff = df_diff.fillna("No Marks") # Fill NA with 'no marks', marks on the second excel will be retained
df_list_final = df_list_2.append(df_diff) # Add all names that did not match
df_list_final = df_list_final.drop(['index'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True) # Remove index column and reindex

print(df_list_final)
```

Output

```
     Names         A         B         C         D
0  Lambrie        90        85       NaN       NaN
1     Wade        70        50       NaN       NaN
2  Jurgens  No Marks  No Marks  No Marks  No Marks
3   Magdel  No Marks  No Marks  No Marks  No Marks
4     Liam        60        50        10        50
```